# Me da el Error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing, insert

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un programa en JavaSwing que registra personas y las va guardando en MySQL, todos los campos son String menos el de fecha_nacimiento y fecha_fallecimiento que son date y este segundo es nullable. A la hora de crear una persona y meterla en la BD me falla y me lanza este error:

"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

esta es el insert que hago

```
String cadena_conexion = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/organizer";
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(cadena_conexion, "root", "");
        Statement sta = conn.createStatement();

        String query = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellidos, dni, fecha_nacimiento, fecha_fallecimiento, genero, email, telefono, direccion, poblacion, provincia, region, cod_postal, pais)"
                + " values('" + campoNombre.getText() + "','" + campoApellidos.getText() + "','" + campoDNI.getText() + "','" + "STR_TO_DATE(" + campoNacimiento.getText() + "','\"%M %d %Y\")" + "','" + "STR_TO_DATE(" + campoFallecimiento.getText() + "','\"%M %d %Y\")" + "','" + campoGenero.getText() + "','"
                + campoEmail.getText() + "','" + campoTelefono.getText() + "','" + campoDireccion.getText() + "','"
                + campoPoblacion.getText() + "','" + campoProvincia.getText() + "','" + campoRegion.getText() + "','"
                + campoPostal.getText() + "','" + campoPais.getText() + "')";

        int resultado = sta.executeUpdate(query);
        if (resultado == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Ha habido un error");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Persona registrada con éxito!");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Y aquí como tengo los campos de esta tabla en bd:

```
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  apellidos varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  dni varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  fecha_nacimiento date NOT NULL,
  fecha_fallecimiento date,
  genero varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  telefono int NOT NULL,
  direccion varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  poblacion varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  provincia varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  region varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  cod_postal varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  pais varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  id_estado INTEGER REFERENCES estados_civiles(id),
  id_nacionalidad INTEGER REFERENCES nacionalidades(id)
```

Busqué este error por foros y veo que puede ser que no se introduzcan los mismos campos que valores por lo que el motor de la base de datos no sepa donde buscar aunque he estado comprobando la consulta y veo que todo está bien, así que no sé que puede ser, saludos!

Comment: 1. ¿Y las claves foráneas? 2. Tu código es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL: tu aliado aquí es el `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Esto es un error de sintaxis, el error es claro al decir `El recuento de columnas no coincide con el recuento de valores en la fila 1`. Tu tabla pide 16 datos, de los cuales solo le mandas 14.

Comment: imprime en la consola el string del insert y compara si tiene todos los valores esperados por la tabla...

Comment: La tabla me pide 16 datos pero es que ya especifico los campos después del INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellidos...) deberia de ponerme las otras claves como null no?